# How to apply a command to subfolders in a folder, and create a new folder with each output?

Tags: bash, terminal, directory, subdirectory, txt

I have several subfolders in a folder which each contain a file called "README.txt". I would like the following two commands to be applied to each subfolder:

```
#identify sequence from README.txt where a line contains 'xyz'
seq= sed -nE '/xyz/{ s/^.*Series:([^,]+),.*/\1/; p; }' README.txt
echo $seq



 #apply this command to convert filetype and copy the file of interest
dcm2niix_afni $seq -o /subfolder-directory /my-directory
```

1. How do I apply these commands to the subfolders in my folder?
2. I would like the output of the commands to be placed into a new folder, of the same name as the subfolder from which the file is from.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you lose the backticks on your `sed` command?

Comment: I don't think so because that portion works fine for me.

Comment: Put a valid [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) and paste your script at https://shellcheck.net for validation/recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

@sk23 It would be much better to provide:

1. An example of the `README.txt` file context.
2. What output exactly do you expect from the `sed` command?
3. What is the output of the `dcm2niix_afni` command - it is a newly generated file probably?
4. Clarify in detail what you mean by "I would like the output of the commands to be placed into a new folder, of the same name as the subfolder from which the file is from."

**But until then** you may review the following script as a hint to be completed to reach your requirements.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

## User defined Variables
# Main folder path
_mainFolder='./main_folder'

# File name to process
_fileName='README.txt'

while IFS='' read -r _file ;do
  seq="$(sed -nE '/xyz/{ s/^.*Series:([^,]+),.*/\1/; p; }' "${_file}")"
  ## If you need to redirect the `sed` command output to a file
  ## let's say `README.txt-sed.log` in each relevant folder, un-comment the next line.
  # echo "${seq}" > "${_file}-seq.log"
  echo "Sed output for the ${_file}"
  echo "${seq}"

  # Any other relevant command may be added from here.

  # To here.
done <<< "$(find "${_mainFolder}" -name "${_fileName}" -type f)"

exit 0
```